# WPF RichTextBox scrolling does not work if window is minimized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, richtextbox

I need the following scrolling behavior, but this only works, if the window is not minimized. Is there a solution that works, even if the window is minimized?

c#

```
private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox.VerticalOffset + richTextBox.ViewportHeight >= richTextBox.ExtentHeight)
    {
        richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextChanged="richTextBox_TextChanged">
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If the Window is minimized, I wonder how you spot the problem??

Comment: The scrollbar is at bottom and i minimize the window. Later when something was appended to the RichTextBox the scrollbar is no longer at the bottom. But if i don't minimize the window it works.

Comment: ViewportHeight is 0.0, when the window is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `ScrollToEnd` also in the `StateChanged` event of the window. So it is done when the window returns from minimized state.

Comment: Then the scrollbar is always at bottom, if the window is restored from minimized.

Comment: I thought exactly that was your aim: to have it scrolled to the end. Or what do you mean with scrollbar at bottom

Comment: If new text is appended to the RichTextBox, and the scrollbar is at end before the text is appended, then ScrollToEnd() shall be called after the new text is appended, otherwise ScrollToEnd() shall not be called.

Comment: Complicated :-) You could set a flag when text is appended. Then you can check this flag after returning from minimized state.